# Kernel Panics in Macbook Pro model A2141

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

Getting regular shutdowns due to a kernel panic regardless of what programs are running. Can someone please help in deciphering this error message? From what I read it might be a bad memory chip? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80165e19b9): [kalloc.type.var2.8192]: element modified after free (off:656, val:0x0400000000000000, sz:8192, ptr:0xffffff9b91558000)
  656: 0x0400000000000000
 3800: 0x0400000000000000
Panicked task 0xffffffa05dcde258: 3 threads: pid 303: com.apple.AppleU
Backtrace (CPU 0), panicked thread: 0xffffffa52ae890c8, Frame : Return Address
0xffffffea2214f3b0 : 0xffffff8015e6f4fd 
0xffffffea2214f400 : 0xffffff8015fc3c54 
0xffffffea2214f440 : 0xffffff8015fb36d9 
0xffffffea2214f4a0 : 0xffffff8015e0f951 
0xffffffea2214f4c0 : 0xffffff8015e6f7dd 
0xffffffea2214f5b0 : 0xffffff8015e6ee87 
0xffffffea2214f610 : 0xffffff80165dceab 
0xffffffea2214f700 : 0xffffff80165e19b9 
0xffffffea2214fb60 : 0xffffff8015edd364 
0xffffffea2214fbc0 : 0xffffff8015e7d756 
0xffffffea2214fbe0 : 0xffffff8015e4859e 
0xffffffea2214fc10 : 0xffffff8016572403 
0xffffffea2214fc90 : 0xffffff801657215c 
0xffffffea2214fcc0 : 0xffffff8015e494f0 
0xffffffea2214fd60 : 0xffffff8015e604a2 
0xffffffea2214fdd0 : 0xffffff8015e60b27 
0xffffffea2214fef0 : 0xffffff8015f98f53 
0xffffffea2214ffa0 : 0xffffff8015e0fdb6 

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffffa52ae890c8): com.apple.AppleUserHIDDrivers

Mac OS version:
22F66

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 22.5.0: Mon Apr 24 20:51:50 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.121.2~5/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7E997BC9-2104-3D4D-9AAE-17BD7A3FEC2D
roots installed: 0
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000015a00000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8015c00000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000015adc000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8015cdc000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8015b00000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1885319844713
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x000001b6f5d1dcf6
  Sleep   : 0x000001ad6bd90e29 0x000010bc7b79e9cc 0x000001830af87169
  Wake    : 0x000001ada0f3ab02 0x000011bb5ab30d52 0x000001ad7ffd219d
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffff905cd15000 - 0xffffffb05cd15000
  . PGZ   : 0xffffff905cd15000 - 0xffffff905ed16000
  . VM    : 0xffffff905ed16000 - 0xffffff952b515000
  . RO    : 0xffffff952b515000 - 0xffffff96c4d15000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffff96c4d15000 - 0xffffff9b91515000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffff9b91515000 - 0xffffffa05dd15000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffffa05dd15000 - 0xffffffa52a515000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffffa52a515000 - 0xffffffa9f6d15000
  . DATA  : 0xffffffa9f6d15000 - 0xffffffb05cd15000
  Metadata: 0xffffffb07cd25000 - 0xffffffb09cd25000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffffb09cd25000 - 0xffffffb09fd25000
  Extra   : 0 - 0

last started kext at 1845736409457: >!UAudio    540.8 (addr 0xffffff7fab33f000, size 335872)
last stopped kext at 1813196480487: >!UAudio    540.8 (addr 0xffffff7fab33f000, size 335872)
loaded kexts:
@filesystems.smbfs  5.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4388.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4387.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    6440.7
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   131
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.9
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    4.1.2
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.1.2
>!AGFXHDA   240.1
>!ABridgeAudio!C    340.1
>!A!IKBLGraphics    20.0.6
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 7.1.18
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   7.1.18
>pmtelemetry    1
@filesystems.nfs    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  198.100.13
>!AMuxControl2  7.1.18
>AGDCBacklightControl   7.1.18
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 20.0.6
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>BridgeAudioCommunication   340.1
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!AMCCSControl  1.16
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.lifs   1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   627.100.6
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   2142.120.7
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac   1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AUserConsent  1
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    403
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
@kec.Compression    1
@kec.!AEncryptedArchive 1
>!UAudio    540.8
|IOAVB!F    1140.6
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    1150.2
>!AActuatorDriver   6440.7
>!AHIDKeyboard  231
>!AMultitouchDriver 6440.7
>!AInputDeviceSupport   6440.8
>!AHS!BDriver   6440.7
>IO!BHIDDriver  9.0.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
>!AAudioClockLibs   240.1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  4.1.2
|IOAudio!F  440.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>IOHIDPowerSource   1
>!ACallbackPowerSource  1
|IO!BSerialManager  9.0.0
|IO!BPacketLogger   9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CTransport    9.0.0
>IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport    9.0.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 4.1.2
@kext.AMDSupport    4.1.2
|CSR!BHost!CUSBTransport    9.0.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   9.0.0
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    9.0.0
>!ARSMChannel   1
|IORSM!F    1
>!AIPAppender   1.0
>!AGraphicsControl  7.1.18
>driverkit.serial   6.0.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   475.40.6
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.5.1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
@!AGPUWrangler  7.1.18
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    7.1.18
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  597
|IOGraphics!F   597
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.5.1
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.5.1
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  336.50.1
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!ASyntheticGame!C  10.6.3
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.81
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.3
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!ABCMWLANCoreMac   1.0.0
|IO80211!F  1200.13.0
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
>!AOLYHALMac    1
|IOSerial!F 11
>corecapture    1.0.4
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   1150.2
|IOSkywalk!F    1.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 9.0.0
|IOReport!F 47
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  554
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  235.100.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  482.120.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  482.120.2
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACyrus    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
$!AImage4   5.0.0
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 12.0
```

Comment: Have you tried running the built-in [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) to confirm if the memory is bad?

Comment: Yes, but it does not show any issues. I have read that it may take an overnight or longer test with a third party memory test program to find an intermittent issue like that but being a PC person (this is my wife's Mac) I am not sure what to use for that. Next step may be the Apple store but was hoping the error report above would point to something we could fix ourselves since it is out of warranty.